# No Such File exception in Runnable Jar file

Tags: java

I am trying to create a runnable jar file. My project includes models.txt file. My project works perfectly in eclipse with no error but when exported to a runnable jar file, It doesn't work. I hereby attach the error and the piece of code where the file is been called.

```
public static HashMap<String, RenderModel>  getModelList(String file) throws IOException {
    List<String> data;
    HashMap<String, RenderModel> namesToModels = new HashMap<String, RenderModel>();

    if (file != null) {
        data = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } else {
        String path = "models/models.txt";
        data = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path),  StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    Iterator<String> dataIterator = data.iterator();
    while (dataIterator.hasNext()) {
        String dataLine = dataIterator.next();
        System.out.println(dataLine);
        String[] line = dataLine.split("; ");
        String key = line[0];
        String valueObj = line[1];
        String valueMtl = line[2];
        float scale = Float.parseFloat((String) line[3]);
        RenderModel v = new RenderModel(valueObj, valueMtl, scale);
        namesToModels.put(key, v);
    }
    RenderModel v =  new RenderModel("custom", "custom", 1.0f);
    namesToModels.put("Choose Model from file", v);
    return namesToModels;
}
```

*Error Image:*

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Add code as text not as image

Comment: In your jar you have no src Folder.

Comment: In eclipse, I have src folder and everything works fine. how to create src folder in jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are in the `Jar` and you cannot read them, try accessing the files by doing:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
```

Use this instead for static methods:

```
ClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
```

Where `fileName` is the name of the file and `ClassName` the name of the class from which the statement is called.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the path of the model.txt is 'src/models/model.txt'. When your project is packaged the src folder is not included usually. Then you must change the file location; could be better put the file outside the jar, but inside the java classpath.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you do not have any file on the path `src/models/models.txt` when you run your jar else where, this path is only present in your IDE (ofcourse you can place your jar in a location from where it can reach that path, but this is not how it is supposed to be), when you package your project into a jar file it is packed in the package `models` and you can if you want to have it as default file read it via [classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26997556/1113392).